# Restrict CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint & CsHybridApplicationEndpoint to a particular security group

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

Is it possible to restrict CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint & CsHybridApplicationEndpoint to a particular security group in skype for business hybrid instance?

Comment: I believe using these are already restricted to the Tenant Administrator.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EricDahlvang, sorry about the unclear question. The ask is not for the cmdlets but for the application endpoints creating with those cmdlets. Is it possible to restrict access of the application endpoints to a particular security group. I have gone through the documentation at [MSDOCS] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/?view=skype-ps) , but not able to find any reference to audience

Comment: I don't think that is an option.  However, you can add authentication to the bot itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp